# Mouse constantly scrolling down

Tags: drivers, 18.04, mouse, scrolling

I recently installed a new SSD and installed linux on it. I was running Windows 10 originally, now I'm dual booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18. The installation of the OS worked fine. But after that day I began noticing that my mouse is constantly "scrolling down" as if I'm constantly scrolling the wheel downwards. I can't use my mouse properly. Everywhere my mouse rests at, its like I'm constantly scrolling downwards at that location.

It doesn't occur all the time. For example, I'm fine on websites -> the page doesn't keep scrolling down. But I open many browser tabs, and if i just move my mouse of one of the tabs, the the right-most tab gets selected. If I open LibreOffice, the sheet keeps scrolling infinitely to the right.

Does anyone know what could have caused this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unbelievable, but the problem was that my wireless keyboard and my wireless mouse's receivers were both on adjacent usb ports. when i moved my mouse's reciever to a further away port, I found that my mouse was not being weird any more, but my keyboard was acting funny. Turns out **my keyboard's battery was running low and it was interfering with my mouse**

Comment: Had this exact issue and I think mine was being caused by interference between my bluetooth headset and mouse.  After unplugging the mouse and using a wired one, the issue went away.